# docker-compose build problems

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have received a docker-compose file with version 3.9. When I try to build it on my Linux Ubuntu18 I get the following error message:

#### Try with version: '3.9'

`ERROR: Version in "./docker-compose.yml" is unsupported. You might be seeing this error because you're using the wrong Compose file version. Either specify a supported version (e.g "2.2" or "3.3") and place your service definitions under the` services`key, or omit the`version`key and place your service definitions at the root of the file to use version 1. For more on the Compose file format versions, see https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/`

#### Try with version: '3.3'

When I change the version to 3.3 it builds something but then aborts with this warning and error message:

`WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated! zlib1g libpng12-0 libfreetype6 zlib1g-dev libpng12-dev libfreetype6-dev libjpeg62-turbo libjpeg62-turbo-dev libzip2 libzip-dev E: There are problems and -y was used without --force-yes ERROR: Service 'webserver' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y libfreetype6-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libpng-dev libzip-dev && a2enmod rewrite && a2enmod headers' returned a non-zero code: 100`

**My docker-compose.yml file**

```yaml
version: '3.9'

volumes:
  code:

services:
  webserver:
    build: webserver
    container_name: webserver
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ./webserver:/var/www/html
      - ./webserver/php-ini-overwrites.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.de/php-ini-overwrites.ini
  
  database:
    image: mariadb:10.5
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: mariadb
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_USER=user123
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    volumes:
      - "./dbdata:/home"
      - "./dbdata/mariadb10:/var/lib/mysql"
```

Comment: 1. You can download the latest version of Docker Compose from the official Docker documentation.
2. Downgrade the version of the docker-compose.yml file format to a supported version such as 3.3.

Comment: Note that with the latest versions of docker-compose, you can simply drop the `version` attribute in the compose file.

Comment: It looks like docker-compose works when you set it to 3.3. It then allows a problem you have with your Dockerfile to surface.

Comment: I think the most recent actual numbered version of the Compose file format is 3.8; see for example the [version 3 format history](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#version-3) (I know the Docker docs use `3.9` elsewhere).  If you are using the older Python version of Compose, you can't remove the `version:` line, since this will cause the file to be interpreted as a very old version 1 Compose file.  I think @HansKilian is right and the _real_ problem is in your Dockerfile, though.